# Question preview not showing in "tagged" pages

Tags: support, questions

When I hover over a question in the main page the question is previewed in the hover over text. But when I click on one of the tags and hover over any question, in that page, the preview is not shown.

For example:

1. Hover over any question on the main page -- you will see a preview.
2. Hover over any question under the ["stackoverflow" tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) -- you won't see the question preview.

I have checked this on Firefox 3.5.3 and IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the front page, you only see the titles of the questions. You have the extra tooltip if you want to linger.

But on the rest of the pages, like the tagged questions page, you already have the preview showing directly under the question title.

> [image: differences and planes and trains]

You don't need to have the `TITLE` attribute of the link of a question repeat exactly what's showing below it unless you want redundancy. And for screen readers, it's extra noise.

Comment: The lack of illustration is shattering!

Comment: Where there's a post, there's a reason for Paint!

Comment: That's how I like it :)

Comment: Feel so... dirty...

Comment: It feels so... good!